# Fetch Date from mysql db into dropdown box in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, combobox, fetch

I am developing user edit form where users can edit their info. I wants only that date come in combo box which was user add in table as Date of Birth. In following code I successfully pull Month into Combo box which user added in table.

IN FOLLOWING LINE I RUN SELECT QUERY TO FETCH DATA FROM DB INCLUDING YEAR, MONTH AND DAY:

```
<?php
$cnic_selected=$_POST['all_cnic'];

if(isset($cnic_selected))
{
$query = mysql_query("SELECT refer_id, emp_name, emp_father, emp_cnic, YEAR(emp_dob) AS byear, MONTH(emp_dob) AS bmonth, DAY(emp_dob) AS bday FROM staff_users WHERE emp_cnic = '$cnic_selected'");

$count = mysql_num_rows($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query))
{
$ref = $row->refer_id;
$name = $row->emp_name;
$fname = $row->emp_father;
$cnic = $row->emp_cnic;
$byear = $row->byear;
$bmonth = $row->bmonth;
$bday = $row->bday;
    }

?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<table width="95%">
<form name="edituserform" action="" method="Post" onSubmit="return validateform(this);">

<tr><td width="125px"><b>Referral Code</b></td>
<td><?php echo $ref; ?></td></tr>

<tr><td><b>Full Name</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="emp_name" id="emp_name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
</td></tr>

<tr><td><b>Father's Name</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="emp_father" id="emp_father" value="<?php echo $fname; ?>" />
</td></tr>

<tr><td><b>CNIC Number</b></td>
<td><?php echo $cnic; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Date of Birth</b></td>
<td>

/* Run Loop to generate 31 days of the month */
<select name="dt">
<option value='--'>--</option>
<?php 
for ($d=1; $d<32; $d++)
{
"<option value='$d'>$d</option>";
 }
?>
</select>

/* Here I manually type months list. Use "Selected" to fetch that month which user select in DB */

<select name="month">
<option value="--">--</option>
<option value='01' <?php echo ($bmonth == 1) ? 'selected="selected"': ''; ?>>
Jan</option>
<option value='02' <?php echo ($bmonth == 2) ? 'selected="selected"': ''; ?>>
Feb</option>
<option value='03' <?php echo ($bmonth == 3) ? 'selected="selected"': ''; ?>>
Mar</option>
<option value='04' <?php echo ($bmonth == 4) ? 'selected="selected"': ''; ?>>
Apr</option>
<option value='05' <?php echo ($bmonth == 5) ? 'selected="selected"': ''; ?>>
May</option>
<option value='06' <?php echo ($bmonth == 6) ? 'selected="selected"': ''; ?>>
Jun</option>
<option value='07' <?php echo ($bmonth == 7) ? 'selected="selected"': ''; ?>>
Jul</option>
<option value='08' <?php echo ($bmonth == 8) ? 'selected="selected"': ''; ?>>
Aug</option>
<option value='09' <?php echo ($bmonth == 9) ? 'selected="selected"': ''; ?>>
Sep</option>
<option value='10' <?php echo ($bmonth == 10) ? 'selected="selected"': ''; ?>>
Oct</option>
<option value='11' <?php echo ($bmonth == 11) ? 'selected="selected"': ''; ?>>
Nov</option>
<option value='12' <?php echo ($bmonth == 12) ? 'selected="selected"': ''; ?>>
Dec</option>
</select>


<select name="year">
<option value='--'>--</option>
<?php
for ($y=2000; $y>1950; $y--)
{ 
echo "<option value='$y'>$y</option>";
}
?>
</select>
</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Now my question is Please tell how to pull Year and Day from table into combo box which user was added while I am using Loop to generate years and days!??

Regards,

MAT

Answer (score 0):

For days you are missing an echo and a check as to which day is selected

```
<?php 
for ($d=1; $d<32; $d++)
{
"<option value='$d'>$d</option>";
 }
?>
```

Should be

```
<?php 
for ($d=1; $d<32; $d++)
{
if($d==$bday)
{
  echo "<option value='$d' selected='selected'>$d</option>";
}
else
{
  echo "<option value='$d'>$d</option>";
}
}
?>
```

Same for year

```
for ($y=2000; $y>1950; $y--)
{ 
   if($y==$byear)
   {
   echo "<option value='$y' selected='selected'>$y</option>";
   }
   else
   {
   echo "<option value='$y'>$y</option>";
   }
}
```